# re_write page outside wordpress folder

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect write a re_write rule to handle article1 to blog/article1
where blog is a wordpress world that has blog/.htaccess too

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under **DOCUMENT_ROOT** directory (parent dir of /blog):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(article1)/?$ blog/$1 [L,R,NC]
```